# How to resize a compose window programmatically after it has been created

Tags: kotlin, desktop, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

Is there a way to resize a Compose Multiplatform desktop window after it has been created?

I already tried setting it through the windowState (which makes sense that it doesn't work as it says changes to the initial values won't change or recreate the state after it has been created) and through window.size.
Both approaches lead to nothing.

```
fun main() = application {
    val windowState = rememberWindowState()

    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        state = windowState
    ) {
        windowState.size = DpSize(1000.dp, 1000.dp) // not working
        window.size = Dimension(1000, 1000) // also not working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't change compose state directly from composable functions. Use side effects instead - check out [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) for more details

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    windowState.size = DpSize(1000.dp, 1000.dp)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason why setting the size didn't work in the my case.
The calls to set the size were to close to the creation of the window.
Both methods are working if i put a delay of 1000ms before the calls (either with LaunchedEffect or with a coroutine scope).

Comment: A delay is not the correct fix. The correct fix is to use a `LaunchedEffect` or other side effect, as shown by @PhilDukhov.

Comment: Even with Launched effect there has to be still some time in between the call or it doesn't work.    
The mention delay was just for testing purposes. In a real application scenario i'd use a side effect for sure.